# Minix 3.2.1 get_uptime usage

Tags: c, timer, minix

Hi I try to calculate time that spend through boot operations;
I put get_uptime() just before switch_to_user() function call in kernel/main.c

```
printf("Uptime= %d \n",get_uptime());
```

however after building and reboot result shown as 0.
Is there a missing point?